# Where does pymssql get it's error codes from?

Tags: sql-server, pymssql

I'm curious as to where pymssql gets its error codes from.

If I get an `OperationalError: (18456, "Login failed for user '***'.DB-Lib error message 18456, severity 14)`, I know that the 18456 comes from the `sys.messages` in MS SQL. However if I get an `OperationalError: (20009, 'Net-Lib error during Connection refused')`, I have no idea where the 20009 is coming from. In the `sys.messages` table I only see `The article '%s' could not be added to the publication '%s'.` for 20009

Answer (score 1):

According to the FreeTDS documentation:

> If you get message 20009, remember you haven't connected to the machine. It's a configuration or network issue, not a protocol failure. Verify the server is up, has the name and IP address FreeTDS is using, and is listening to the configured port.

http://www.freetds.org/userguide/confirminstall.htm (Example 3-5) Good luck!